# Cannot resolve symbol (after Android Studio update) but the project builds for app/library project

Tags: android, dependencies, project, upgrade, resolve

I have an an Android Studio project A which is an app, and a project B which is a library project. I have included project B in project A. Project B has some dependencies (android async http, and org.json) that are used in both project B and project A. I upgraded Android Studio to 2.2 Preview 2, and am now having an issue where all of my usages of android async http are saying Cannot Resolve Symbol. However, my JSON usages are just fine. When I build the project, I get no errors and can run it just fine. How can I fix the Cannot Resolve Symbol issue in Android Studio?

I have tried

1. cleaning & rebuilding both projects
2. making a change in the app's build.gradle & syncing grade
3. re-arranging the order of dependencies
4. sync project with gradle files
5. delete android async http.xml from .idea/libraries & sync project with gradle files
6. opening and closing android studio
7. setting minifyEnabled=true in the app & library

Is there something I am missing?

app > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 33
        versionName "2.3"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':mylibrary')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
}
```

library > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/org.json-20120521.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.5.jar')
}
```